# Peltier Effect in Nature?

Tags: thermodynamics, thermoelectricity

Are there examples of the [Peltier effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermoelectric_effect) occurring naturally, or has it only ever been artificially produced? Has there ever been what amounts to a 'natural refrigerator' discovered? And what would be the likelihood of finding such a thing if we haven't already?

Answer (score 0):

As long as a current is going through the interface of two materials whose Seebeck coefficient differ, the Peltier effect should occur. So your question can be recast as "Are there examples of an electric current going through two adjacent materials in nature?". I would say yes, there is. A thunder comes to mind, in which case electricity can "flow" through several different materials.
The Peltier effect could be small, of course, since it is proportional to Seebeck coefficient and the absolute temperature, nonetheless it should still be non zero.

Regarding the probability to find a natural refrigerator working via the Peltier effect, I would say virtually null. Peltier coolers are made of several n-p legs (amongst a lot of other things). If you're extremely lucky to find a single such pair, it wouldn't make what one would call a refrigerator. This really has to be cautiously engineered.